# Integrate Crystal Report in WPF VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm stuck with integrating crystal reports in WPF VB.net. Can somebody please share a sample project or sample code? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Regards

Comment: If the reports do not already exist, have you considered using Microsoft Reports and the Report Viewer? I have had good experiences with it.

Comment: @CStick- The reports already exists in Crystal report format and its a very complicated report.

Comment: Ah, too bad, MS reports are easily integrated.